# How can I run an mpi executable so that top shows one process

Tags: mpi

Is it possible to run an mpi executable using multiple threads so that on doing "top" one sees only one process with the full cpu usage?

For example, if I run "mpiexec -np 4 ./executable" and do "top", I see 4 processes with different PIDs, each using 100% cpu. I would like to see a single process with a unique PID using 400% cpu.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: Maybe 4 threads inside one process?!

Comment: @Zulan Multiple reasons: 1. Sometimes each process uses less than 100%. It would be nice if I could see the total usage directly. 2. Compare cpu usage with an openmp version of the same code. 3. Ability to kill the code with a single pid.

Comment: Please see my edit to address this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, that is not possible.** MPI is explicitly designed for separate processes. They will inevitably show up as separate processes on top.

Now there may be some esoteric MPI implementations based on threads instead of processes, but I highly doubt these would be conforming and practically usable MPI implementations.

**Edit**:

1.-2. The program `atop` in "Accumulated per program" mode (press 'p') might do what you want.
3. usually, if you kill `mpiexec` / `mpirun`, it will terminate all ranks. Otherwise, consider `killall`.

I can see how that may be convenient for a superficial glance about performance, but you should consider investing in learning more sophisticated performance analysis tools for parallel applications.

Comment: Well, you can still do multi-threading, right? [Here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/mpithreads_both.c)

Comment: Sure you can do that, but I don't see how that is even related to the question. Then it's just a threaded program in MPI clothing.

Comment: I see. I was looking at it from programming perspective. Now that I read it again...The question was about running an MPI program which could be multi-threaded or not, cool.